# Using integers in text-query

Tags: parsing, solr

I am indexing a table of companies, where a lot of them have names starting with an integer, e.g:

2partner
3m
etc.

But when I try to do a simple solr-query like "2partner" (in Solr's webinterface), the integer "2" is removed by the query parser. Here's the debug:

```
<lst name="debug">
<str name="rawquerystring">2partner</str>
<str name="querystring">2partner</str>
<str name="parsedquery">text:partner</str>
<str name="parsedquery_toString">text:partner</str>
```

How do I avoid that?

Thanks in advance :-)

/Carsten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using a [WordDelimiterFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory) with splitOnNumerics activated. Check the analyzers of the field you are storing this data into.

Comment: I have indeed the WordDelimiterFilter define here:

<fieldType name="textTight" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" >
  <analyzer>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0"/>
...

but a) splitOnNumerics is not activated, and b) it is only defined on the fieldType "textTight" which AFAIK I am not using

Comment: Oh bloody comment format... :-) Here's a Pastie with my entire schema.xml: http://pastie.org/1200681

Comment: The 'text' fieldType uses a LetterTokenizerFactory. According to the doc, any non-letter characters will be discarded when using that tokenizer. http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.LetterTokenizerFactory

Comment: Oh... Well still I have a lot to learn about Solr. :-) Which tokenizer would you recommend for a "simple" text-field?

Comment: The StandardTokenizerFactory or WhitespaceTokenizerFactory are usually good choices. Then proceed with some filters. It all depends on your need. Check the schema.xml provided in the example folder of the latest Solr package. Check also the example here: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#Specifying_an_Analyzer_in_the_schema

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I've changed to the StandardTokenizerFactory (and its "sibling" StandardFilter) and I am now reindexing my data. I look forward to see the result.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know, that I have now reindexed my data during the night with the StandardTokenizer, and now everything works as expected. Thank you very much.